# Aggregate Stream Data with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am producing messages to Kafka with a code like that:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("acks", "all");
props.put("retries", 0);
props.put("batch.size", 16384);
props.put("linger.ms", 1);
props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "testo");
props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

Producer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>(
    "topico",
    String.format("{\"type\":\"test\", \"t\":%.3f, \"k\":%d}", System.nanoTime() * 1e-9, i)));
}
```

I want to count to total messages within last hour with Kafka Streams (0.10.0.1). I've tried that:

```java
final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
final KStream<String, String> metrics = builder.stream(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), "topico");
metrics.countByKey(TimeWindows.of("Hourly", 3600 * 1000)).mapValues(Object::toString).to("output");
```

I am so new to Kafka/Streams. How can I do it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give a data example, with input, output, and expected output. The code seems fine. Not sure what the issues is you are facing.

Comment: Also, what is the error/problem that you are facing? It's not mentioned in your question.  I do see a couple of problems with the little bit of code that you shared, but before jumping to premature conclusions it would help, as Matthias J. Sax said, if you could share more information -- notably about the Kafka Streams related code: 1. the configuration settings you have defined relating to Kafka Streams, and 2. the full topology definition etc. including the part where you actually start the topology via sth like `KafkaStreams#start()`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all .. You lack this code to actually start your streaming process..

```
KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder, config);   
streams.start();    
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

Answer (score 1):

To aggregate two streams you can make use of the join method. 
There are [different joins](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#joining) available in kstreams.

For example: if you want to join `kstream` with `ktable`:

```
KStream<String, String> left = builder.stream("topic1");
KTable<String, String> right = builder.table("topic2");

left.leftjoin((right, (leftValue, rightValue) -> Customfunction(rightValue, leftValue))
```

finally start the kstream

```
streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, config);
streams.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also new with kafka streams, I don't know the old api but with new one (2.1.x) something like this should work

```
 kstream.mapValues((readOnlyKey, value) -> "test")
                    .groupByKey()
                    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(1000 * 60))
                    .count()
                    .toStream()
                    .selectKey((key, value) -> Instant.ofEpochMilli(key.window().end())
                            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.HOURS).toEpochMilli())
                    .groupByKey(Serialized.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.Long())).reduce((reduce, newVal) -> reduce + newVal)
                    .toStream().peek((key, value) -> log.info("{}={}",key,value));
```